# First Instance of the Classic Alien Depiction

Tags: aliens, history-of

I was just wondering where the first instance of the classic tall, skinny-limbed, greenish grey, large bulb head, and black eyes alien was shown in either film and TV or described in book form.

Comment: You appear to be asking about the so-called "Grey" alien archetype, in which case the answer is over here: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/72572/where-does-the-archetypal-image-of-the-grey-alien-come-from

Comment: As Ixrec said, the question has been asked before.  I would also like to mention that the "classic" (i.e., oldest and most traditional) depiction of an alien in science fiction is **not** the "grey", but the ubiquitous "little green men".